# Why are my areas in my shape file in geopandas zero?

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas

I am in Python and I have a shape file that I have loaded into a dataframe (date). When I print `data[[’geometry’].head()` you can see that the GPS coordinates print in the terminal. But when I try to calculate the area of the polygons I get zero values (0.0000).

Why is this?

```
Import necessary modules
import geopandas as gpd

#Read file using gpd.read_file()
data = gpd.read_file("/kaggle/input/aeso-connection-list/Apr_2023_ProjectList_Shapefile.shp")

print(data.head(2))

print(data['geometry'].head())

#Make a selection that contains only the first five rows
selection = data[0:5]

#Iterate over rows and print the area of a Polygon 
for index, row in selection.iterrows():
    #Get the area of the polygon
    poly_area = row['geometry'].area
    #Print information for the user
    print("Polygon area at index {index} is: {area:.3f}".format(index=index, area=poly_area))
```

Terminal output:

```
             Status_1                                 Project_Na  ProjNo  \
0  Recently Cancelled  P1505 ATCO City of Grande Prairie New POD  1505.0   
1              Active           P1567 EDPR Sharp Hills Wind Farm  1567.0   

          Planning_1  Project_Ty MW_Type  Stage_1 Disclaimer Inclusion  \
0  20-Grande Prairie  Connection    Load      5.0       None       Yes   
1           42-Hanna  Connection    Wind      5.0       None       Yes   

   Applied_On  ...     EN1_ISD  EN2_STS_MW EN2_DTS_MW       EN2_ISD  \
0  2013-12-10  ...        None        None       None          None   
1  2014-06-04  ...  2023-02-10         289          0  Aug 15, 2023   

                         EN2 EN3_STS_MW EN3_DTS_MW EN3_ISD EN3  \
0                         NA       None       None    None  NA   
1  289 MW STS - Aug 15, 2023       None       None    None  NA   

#************************************

                      geometry  
0  POINT (-118.87506 55.21973)  
1  POINT (-110.63801 51.73891)  
[2 rows x 22 columns]

#*************************************
0    POINT (-118.87506 55.21973)
1    POINT (-110.63801 51.73891)
2    POINT (-113.51863 53.52077)
3    POINT (-113.31835 51.88593)
4    POINT (-110.90825 53.97699)

#*************************************
Polygon area at index 0 is: 0.000
Polygon area at index 1 is: 0.000
Polygon area at index 2 is: 0.000
Polygon area at index 3 is: 0.000
Polygon area at index 4 is: 0.000
```

Comment: What's the output if you add `print(row['geometry'])` just before `poly_area = row['geometry'].area`?

Comment: Your problem is that you are using Point geometries, not Polygon geometries.

Comment: Why did you expect the are of a point to be larger than 0?